# What attributes does "[RASHCNET]" refer to?

Tags: robocopy

In some of Robocopy options like:

`/a+:[RASHCNET]` - Adds the specified attributes to copied files.

`/a-:[RASHCNET]` - Removes the specified attributes from copied files.

What attributes does `[RASHCNET]` refer to?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The RASHCNETO refers to the following attributes.

```
R – Read only 
A – Archive 
S – System 
H – Hidden
C – Compressed 
N – Not content indexed
E – Encrypted 
T – Temporary
O - Offline
```

Comment: Where did you find this?

Comment: @RobertREvans I know this is old but here is A source(halfway down the page under file attributes): https://ss64.com/nt/robocopy.html